# C adding struct which has been initialized by a function overrides original

Tags: c, c99

Node.h

```
typedef struct Node Node;                                                           
struct Node{
    int rank;
    int marked;
    size_t nSize;
    size_t nCapacity;
    char * name;
    Node * predecessor;
    Table * weights;
    void (*print)(Node * toPrint);  ///< print function for printing all info
    Node ** neighbors;
};
void init_node(Node ** node, char * name, void (*printNode)(Node * n));
```

Node.c

```
void init_node(Node ** node, char * name, void (*printNode)(Node * n)){                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    *node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if ( node == NULL ){
        assert(NULL);
    }
    (*node)->rank=0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    (*node)->marked=0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    (*node)->nSize=0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    (*node)->name=name;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    (*node)->predecessor=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    if ( (*node)->predecessor == NULL ){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        assert(NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    (*node)->nCapacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    (*node)->neighbors=(Node **)calloc((*node)->nCapacity, sizeof(Node *));
    if ( (*node)->neighbors == NULL ){
         assert(NULL);
    }
    (*node)->weights = create(strHash, strEquals, strLongPrint );
    (*node)->print = printNode;
}
```

main.c

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < TEST_AMOUNT ; i++){
        char str[TEST_AMOUNT + 1] ="";
        sprintf(str, "%zu", i);
        Node * n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
        init_node(&n, str, printNode);
        nodes[i] = *n;
        nodes[i].print(&nodes[i]);
    }

    printf("First: %p Second: %p\n", (void *)&nodes[0].name, (void *)&nodes[1].name);
    printf("\n\nCreated an array of %d Nodes\n\n", TEST_AMOUNT);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < TEST_AMOUNT; i++){
        nodes[0].print(&nodes[0]);
    }
```

So I have this node class, and I keep having this issue when I create a node then initialize it in a for loop like above then assign that value to the array. The array then contains TEST_AMOUNT number of the same node rather then a series of nodes labeled 0-TEST_AMOUNT. 
I don't seem to have this problem when I create a node and initialize it outside of the for loop, and was curious as to what was causing this.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Where is the rest of your program? See [mcve]

Comment: `(*node)->name=name;` --> `(*node)->name=strdup(name);`. Also You have many memory leak.

Comment: Also note that a `struct` has no concept of `self` (without an additional layer of OOP), so beyond an educational exercise, why would you want to allocate a pointer to store the same print function in every node when you will have to pass a pointer to the node in a call to the print function to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `malloc()` before calling `init_node`. `init_node()` allocates the space for the node, and assigns to the caller's variable -- that's why you have to pass the address of the variable.

You don't show the declaration of the `nodes` array, but it should be declared as an array of pointers. Then you'll need to indirect through these pointers to access the data in the nodes.

```
Node *nodes[TEST_AMOUNT];

for (size_t i = 0; i < TEST_AMOUNT ; i++){
    char str[TEST_AMOUNT + 1] ="";
    sprintf(str, "%zu", i);
    init_node(&nodes[i], str, printNode);
    nodes[i]->print(nodes[i]);
}
```